# How to share data with a component in Angular within only single browser tab?

Tags: angular, components

I have a navbar(top bar of the page with logo etc) where I would like to dynamically show dropdown options based on the page where the user currently is. Different pages should have different navbar options that dynamically change based on what is chosen on the current page. (for instance if a user selects some checkbox on a page, I want a delete action option on the navbar of the current page)
The page component are not directly related(by parent/ sibling relationships) to the navbar component which is currently a shared component in the layout section of the app.

Let's consider the delete example cited above.
I considered using the emitter and Output functionality to emit the checkbox check action to pick it up in the navbar component and display the delete action accordingly in the navbar. This would work unless I have a parallel tab open with the same app - the navbar would get updated there as well, right? Is there any way to exclusively emit/ share data between components within the current browser tab?

Comment: If it's within the same tab then you can just use a service.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I used a service that was private to the 2 components and had to use the Subject class of RxJS. I had assumed that this would also share information between tabs when I went through the documentation as it was a subscription- it does not. It is apparently restricted to only one instance of your session(a single tab on browser). I have tried and verified. So life is good again.